# Using git reset to merge

Tags: git

My lead says to merge an issue into the main branch, first I should

```
git fetch
git checkout main-branch
git reset --hard origin/main-branch # ???
git checkout my-branch
git merge main-branch
```

This appears to correctly fast-forward merge my local main-branch to match origin. Why is this? Shouldn't it be

```
git merge origin/main-branch
```

or

```
git pull origin main-branch
```

What is the difference?

Comment: I'm sorry for your lead.

Comment: Your lead has probably been bitten by a case where someone "accidentally" did some work on `main-branch`, in which case `git merge origin/main-branch` did the wrong thing. But the `git reset`, while it accomplishes essentially the same thing, should probably be `git merge --ff-only origin/main-branch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` will update your remote branches to have all the new commits in them. So `origin/main-branch` will be updated afterwards. So when you switch to your local `main-branch` and reset to the remote branch, you are resetting the local branch to the updated branch from the remote now.

Usually, you would use `git pull` on the `main-branch` to get this effect. This also has the huge benefit that in case you had some local commits that were not included on the remote branch, they would get merged automatically. So, *be careful* as using `reset --hard` can result in commits getting lost.

Btw. `git pull` is essentially the same as `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, so either is fine. Running `git fetch` manually helps if you have multiple remote branches you would want to update (as `git fetch` fetches all remote branches by default).

Another very safe option would be to use `git pull --ff-only`. This is what I usually do when updating a local branch I do not expect to have any local commits. In case you ever happened to have a local commit that is not part of the remote branch, it will give you a warning and will not merge anything. So you can figure out first, where the commit came from and see for example if you accidentally commited to a wrong branch or something.

Comment: I was under the impression that git reset was for undoing changes, I had no idea it could be used to update a local branch to match a remote. I'm pretty surprised that this is even possible.

Comment: I think there is a typo in: "`git pull` is essentially the same as `git fetch` followed by a `git pull`"

Comment: As its core, `git reset` changes which commit a branch points to. Depending on the type (`--soft`, `--hard` etc.) it does that in a different way. The most dramatical way is `--hard` which essentially throws away the index and the working directory (all uncommited changes are lost), moves the branch to the given commit and checks that out. So you reset completely to the target commit and throw everything else away. But for example `--soft` will only change the pointer but keep all changes (so you do not lose anything).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference, I suppose the rationale is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The combination

```
git fetch
git checkout main-branch
git merge origin/main-branch
```

Would be essentially the same as

```
git checkout main-branch
git pull
```

So that does seem like a lot better than `git reset --hard origin/main-branch`, which just throws away any local commits.

The following

```
git checkout my-branch
git merge main-branch
```

merges changes from main-branch to my-branch.

To "*merge an issue into the main branch*" you should rather do (assuming the issue is fixed on `my-branch`)

```
git checkout main-branch
git merge my-branch
```